# Point layer with random size and rotation

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression

I have a point layer representing trees. This layer uses a SVG symbol.

I set the size with `rand(3, 5)` in map unit (I'm in meters). And the rotation with `rand(0, 359)`. With this, my map looks a bit more "natural"!

My problem is that the random is re-calculated each time I zoom in and out. I want that every new point uses the SVG with a size between 3 and 5 meters, and a rotation between 0 and 359. But once it's done, they don't move anymore.

Is it possible with the geometry generator? If yes, how?

The reason is if I send a map to my customers, and they ask me just to change the title for example, I don't want all my symbol to be also modified!

Comment: You could hardcode the values to the attribute table and use the new columns for symbology.

Comment: It coud be a solution, but I'm trying not to create 2 new attributes (size and rotation). The point layer already has a lot of attributes. So I'm asking if this could be done in the geometry generator!

Comment: you could also derive a value from another field / location (like the cm coordinate digit X for the size and Y for the angle)

Comment: I have tried, but the problem is all my trees are in the same area (it's why a can draw them in "map units"). So the $x and $y are very similar, so if I use something like that for the rotation: $x/$y they all look very close to each other! And for the size, it's even harder cause I want something between 3-5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The idea**
You can create a pseudo-random value that remains constant, based on the inherent properties of each feature with some mathematical operations. Inherent properties can be the x-/y-coordinate values (as proposed already) or `$id` of each feature. As you mentioned, `$x` and `$y` values are too close to each other to work as a kind of "random" value.

But you can use some mathematical operations that turn each number to a hard-to-predict new value that is, however, calculated and thus stable (does not change with pan/zoom). You could use mathematical operations like square root, sinus, cosinus, tangens, logorithm, convert radians to angles and vice versa etc. To improve the "pseudo-random" value, just pick out a few of the digits (not the whole resulting number)  - let's say three digits to get results from 0 (000) to 999. Than scale the result to the range you need - like 0 to 999 should be converted linear to a value from 3 to 5 and/or 0 to 360.

**The implementation**
Let's say you calculate the square root of the x-coordiante value and divide it by the feature's `id` (or some logarithm or sinus of the `id`). Than from the resulting real number take a few digits, let's say three, using the substring function to get the digits from position 8 to 10 (position count includes the whole number, including digit point and integer value before it - you could first substract the rounded value, to get only the positions after the decimal point). You get a value from 0 to 999. With scale_linear, you can scale these values to a range from 3 to 5. The whole expression looks like this:

`scale_linear( substr (sqrt( $x) / $id, 8,3), 0, 999, 3,5)`

and respectively for rotation (here picking 3 digits, starting from postion 4):

`scale_linear( substr (sqrt( $x) / $id, 4,3), 0, 999, 0,360)`

[image]

If your x- and y-coordinates are still too close to produce this pseudo-random effect, you might again use `substr()` - e.g. replace `$x` with `substr ( $x, 3,4)` to get the four digits, starting with position 3 (thus a number consisting of the digits at position 3,4,5 and 6).

To get the starting position of a substring, this can also be based on the value of the `$id` of each feature, together with `scale_linear` function (as digits are limited to 15). To replace the value of `4` in the expression above (the position from where taking three digits should start), you could use this expression - based on the value of the features `$id`, it returns an integer from 3 to 13 that you can use as start position for selecting three digits:

`to_int (scale_linear( $id, 0, count( $id), 3,13))`

Here as well, you could look for more sophisticated solutions by modifying the start position with a pseudo-random function based on the id value (as in the examples above), calculating some square-roots, logarithms or whatever and selecting a certain range (positions) to get some quasi-accidental (hard to predict) values that are however calculated and will thus be stable.